# Numerically solving a partial differential equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, differential-equations

I am trying to numerically solve the following PDE,

$$\frac{\partial u^A}{\partial t} = c_1\frac{\partial^2 u^A}{\partial^2x} \,,$$

where $c_1$ is a constant.  The above can be discretized using the numerical approximations
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u^A}{\partial t} & ~\Rightarrow~ \frac{u_{i}^{t+1} - u_i^t}{\Delta t } \\[5px]
\frac{\partial^2 u^A}{\partial^2x} &~\Rightarrow~ \frac{u_{i+1}^t -2u_i^t+ u_{i-1}^t}{\Delta x^2 }
\end{align}
$$

Gives,

$$\frac{u_{i}^{t+1} - u_i^t}{\Delta t} = c_1\frac{u_{i+1}^t -2u_i^t+ u_{i-1}^t}{\Delta x^2 }$$

The above can be rearranged,

$$
\begin{align}
u_{i}^{t+1} &= u_{i}^t + \frac{c_1 \Delta t}{\Delta x}(u_{i+1}^t -2u_i^t+ u_{i-1}^t) \\[5px]
u_{i+1}^{t+1} &= u_{i+1}^t + \frac{c_1 \Delta t}{\Delta x}(u_{i+2}^t -2u_{i+1}^t+ u_{i}^t)
\end{align}
$$ and so on.

In matrix notation,
$$U^{t+1} = [u_{i}^{t+1},u_{i+1}^{t+1}, \, \dots ,u_{i+n}^{t+1}]$$

Therefore,
$$
U_A^{t+1} = U_A^{t}   + c_1* \text{tridiagonal matrix} * U_A^t
$$

The above can be solved to obtain $U_A^{t+1}$.

Now when there is another species B, the equation will be 
$U_B^{t+1} = U_B^{t}   + c_2* \text{tridiagonal matrix} * U_B^t$

I am solving for the time evolution of function $u$ of species A and B as two separate matrix equations. Could someone suggest if there is a way to formulate this as a single matrix equation? I'm trying to create a diagonal matrix of the constants c and then combine the matrices.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I'm trying an alternate approach. If I were to use the method of lines the equations would be

$$\frac{du^A}{dt} = c_1\frac{u_{i+1}^{t^A} -2u_i^{t^A}+ u_{i-1}^{t^A}}{\Delta x^2 }$$
$$\frac{du^B}{dt} = c_2\frac{u_{i+1}^{t^B} -2u_i^{t^B}+ u_{i-1}^{t^B}}{\Delta x^2 }$$

In the matrix form,
$[\frac{du^A}{dt}  \frac{du^B}{dt}]^T = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}*diagonalmatrix*[u_{i+1}^{t^A} -2u_i^{t^A}+ u_{i-1}^{t^A} ; u_{i+1}^{t^B} -2u_i^{t^B}+ u_{i-1}^{t^B} ]$ ,

where diagonalmatrix contains the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ along its diagonal.

Would this be the right way to proceed? I have the initial condition and boundary conditions.

Comment: Your finite difference equation is explicit with respect to the time step, so why do you even need to work in terms of matrices?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I trying to understand how to implement for the explicit from so that I can implement the implicit form later.

Comment: Do you have access to the IMSL library of subroutines?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Sorry, I haven't had a chance to use IMSL before. I work on MATLAB.I'm trying to formulate the model on my own to get a better understanding on how the system works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is primarily a mathematics question, even if there could be physics application.

Comment: @AaronStevens can the question be migrated to the Mathematics Ex?

Comment: @AaronStevens I just noticed the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662640/converting-the-diffusion-equation-pdes-to-odes-for-use-in-matlab-ode-solvers) helps. The PDE is formulated as an ode by discretizing in space. I'm trying to solve a multicomponent version of the problem posted in the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the time-step taken between the two species is the same, you should be able to just simply combine the two species into a single vector:
$$
U_\text{tot}=\left[\begin{array}{c}u_0^A \\ u_1^A\\ \vdots \\u_{n+1}^A \\ u_0^B \\ u_1^B \\ \vdots \\ u_{n+1}^B \end{array}\right]
$$
And turn the two individual matrix operators into the single matrix,
$$
\mathsf{X}_\text{tot}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\mathsf{X}_A & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathsf{X}_B\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\mathsf{X}_A =c_1 * \text{tridiagonal matrix}$ and $\mathbf 0$ a matrix of 0's. Thus you still have a tridiagonal problem to solve:
$$U^{n+1}_\text{tot}=\mathsf{X}_\text{tot}U^n_\text{tot}$$

On a programming aspect, there probably won't be much of a difference in the timing between doing them separately and together like the above. Maybe a collective few microseconds due to the duplicate calls to the same update function with different vectors and matrices, but you'll probably lose those gains with populating & de-populating $U_\text{tot}$ and $\mathsf {X}_\text{tot}$. Perhaps the combined method would allow you to add in some cross terms (in the operator), so that may be one advantage to running with this method?

Comment: Could you please have a look at the updated post?